# json_decode: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, decode

```
<?php
function get_photos($user_id=XXXX,$count=X,$width=XXX,$height=XXX,$token="XXXX"){
    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token='.$token.'&count='.$count;
    $cache = './BLAH/'.sha1($url).'.json';
    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 1000){
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache), true);
    } else {
        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
    }
    $result = '<div id="instagram">'.PHP_EOL;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($jsonData as $value) {
        $title = (!empty($value->caption->text))?' '.$value->caption->text:'...';
    BLAHBLAH
    }
    $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $result;
}
echo get_photos();
?>
```

What's wrong with `foreach ($jsonData as $value)`? I'm grabbing an array with the "true" argument in json_decode.. isn't that foreach okay?

Here's the json input: http://pastebin.com/EBGG10hx

Comment: **`assoc`**: *When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.* Your decoded data will contain arrays, not objects. Use `$value['caption']['text']`.

Comment: So I leave the foreach as it is and change $title ?

Comment: I tried with this but I'm getting an undefined index

        foreach ($jsonData as $value) {
            $title = $value['caption']['text'];
            $location = $value['location']['name'];
            $result .= "\t".'<a href="'. $title. '">test</a>'.PHP_EOL;
        }